# Polar form of -$2$ - $2\sqrt{2i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

-$2$ - $2\sqrt{2i}$

So I am confused on the $\sqrt{2i}$ part, so what I did was using the rule $\sqrt{ab}$ = $\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ and that gives $\sqrt{2} \sqrt{i}$

-$2$ - $2\sqrt{2i}$ = -2 -2$\sqrt{2} \sqrt{i}$ multiply by $i^\frac{9}{2}$ to get an $i$ therefore it becomes -2 -2$\sqrt{2}$i ; r = 2$\sqrt{3}$ and $\theta$ = $\tan^{-1}({\sqrt{2})}$

so the polar form is 2$\sqrt{3}$ cis($\tan^{-1}({\sqrt{2})}$)

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure the square root covers the $i$ too? And no, you cannot use $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ without being careful

Comment: yes it covers the $i$ .

Answer (score 2):

Note

\begin{align}
-2-2\sqrt{2i}&= -2-2\sqrt2 (e^{i\frac\pi2})^{1/2}\\
&= -2-2\sqrt2e^{i\frac \pi4}\\
&= -4-2i \\
&= 2\sqrt5 e^{i\tan^{-1}\frac12}
\end{align}

Comment: It looks like you have flipped a negative sign from the OP.  The method is fine, though.

Comment: can you do $\sqrt{2i}$ as 1 + i , then do -2 -2(1+i) then go from there for polar form.

Comment: @DougM - right, tkx. will correct

Comment: it should be 2$\sqrt{5}$ @Quanto

Comment: @EM4 - you could. Thanks for pointing out the error

Comment: and I seen my mistake where I did wrong hahah...I should not go fast doing problems 

:)